# How to put a static variable in a parent Object that is different between different children in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Conider I have a Class called `Entity` that has 3 children :
`ClientEntity`, `EmployeeEntity` and `ProductEntity`
I want to have a static attribute `_nextId` (that gives the new id for a new record)
`_nextId` has a different value in each entity, but its a common attribute to all Entity children.

So my question is how can I put `_nextId` in `Entity` class and have methods that change this value, while getting a different value for each child class.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want it to be static? Oh, because it's an id. Why can't you just add it to each class, although I'm not convinced the overall approach is correct.

Comment: i want to put it in a parent class for common methods written in the parent

Comment: But static members aren't overridden, they're hidden. You can put a static id in each subclass and have Entity declare an abstract getNextId method that returns each class's static property. Precisely what assylias said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Entity` is abstract, you could create a :

```
protected abstract getNextId();
```

method which each concrete subclass will need to implement. That implementation can for example rely on a static counter.

Comment: I can't make getNextId() static if it's abstract

Comment: Why do you want to make `getNextId` abstract? A possible implementation in `ClientEntity` would be: `public abstract getNextId() {return ++nextId;}` where `nextId` is a static member of `ClientEntity`. Also `getNextId` should probably be public, not protected.

Comment: so to be clear the method is not static, but i override it in each child to return the static result right ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to hide it. Meaning you need to have the same variable in the subclasses as well.

If you declare a static variable in a superclass, all subclasses access the same variable until they hide it by declaring a variable with the same name themselves.

Comment: and if i have a method in the superclass using this attribute, which one will be called ?

Comment: If you don't override the method in the parent class, the value for the parent class would be returned. If you override getId(), in say ProductEntity, and ProductEntity hides the superclass value, then it would return it's own value - not the parents.